# Django: "detail": "Not found." on Webpage HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: python, django

There are my models below:

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

The views.py is follow:

```
 class RegisterStudent(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    GET stu/
    POST stu/
    '''
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        grade, created = Grade.objects.get_or_create(
        grade=request.data["grade"],
    )
        a_site = Student.objects.create(
            name=request.data["name"],
            grade = grade,
            rollno=request.data["rollno"],
        )
        print(type(a_site.grade))
        return Response(
            data=StudentinGSerializer(a_site).data,
            status

class StudentinGrade(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
        print('You should be the one wrking')
        '''
        GET grade/{grade}/stu/
        POST grade/{grade}/stu/    
        '''
        queryset = Student.objects.all()
        serializer_class = StudentSerializer

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            grade, created = Grade.objects.get_or_create(
            grade=request.data["grade"],
        )
            a_site = Student.objects.create(
                name=request.data["name"],
                grade = grade,
                rollno=request.data["rollno"],
            )
            return Response(
                data=DeviceSerializer(a_site).data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
```

What I am trying to do with first class is just get the data for students, which works.

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('grade/<str:pk>/stu', StudentinGrade.as_view(), name = "grade-stu"),]
```

When I load the page firstly it shows: "detail": "Not found.". Not sure why, because when I post it does accept it and I can see the changes.

I have read the following links but still not sure:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class StudentinGrade(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        print('You should be the one wrking')
        '''
        GET grade/{grade}/stu/
        POST grade/{grade}/stu/    
        '''
        queryset = Student.objects.all()
        serializer_class = StudentSerializer

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            g1= Grade.objects.get(
        grade=kwargs["pk"],
    )
            a_site = Student.objects.create(
            name=request.data["name"],
            grade = g1,
            rollno=request.data["rollno"],
        )
            return Response(
            data=StudentinGSerializer(a_site).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

I was using the wrong view type and fetching the data incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

DRF doesn't allow `get()` method in `UpdateAPIView`. It provides `put` and `patch` method handlers. To Retrieve and Update you can use `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`

Follow the docs [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that error got removed and it shows: "detail": "Not found." And all the details are there.

Comment: Update your question with your modified question.

Comment: I have made the changes.

Comment: In your URL, you use pk is `str`, make it `int` and try.

Comment: Not sure how will that make a difference.

Comment: Did you try it? `pk` is always `int`.

Comment: It is not true, it can be a string. Because I chose the primary key as some other field than id. It is in the model.